# How to put label tooltip in highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, highcharts, label, tooltip, axis-labels

Just like there are tooltips on individual points on the chart, for example in a line chart, I would like to have some tooltip also on hovering over the label. What would be the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I found two options. First would be kind of external, and it is called tooltipsy. Other one is by using the custom-events highcharts plugin. Second one is native to highcharts, I think this is the correct way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the below example - By adding `mouseover` and `mouseout` events to an element, you can call build-in Highcharts tooltip:

```
chart: {
  ...,
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var chart = this,
        xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
        halfTooltipWidth,
        posX,
        posY;

      for (var key in xAxis.ticks) {
        (function(label) {
          label
            .on('mouseover', function(e) {
              chart.tooltip.refresh({
                series: chart.series[0],
                getLabelConfig: function() {}
              });

              halfTooltipWidth = chart.tooltip.label.width / 2;
              posX = label.xy.x - halfTooltipWidth;
              posY = label.xy.y;

              chart.tooltip.move(posX, posY, posX + halfTooltipWidth, posY - 10);
            })
            .on('mouseout', function(e) {
              chart.tooltip.hide();
            });
        })(xAxis.ticks[key].label)
      }

    }
  }
},
tooltip: {
  headerFormat: '',
  formatter: function() {
    if (this.y) {
      return 'Point'
    }

    return 'Custom tooltip'
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2jr0xdcw/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Tooltip

Comment: I actually don't understand the logic in your fiddle.....can you maybe write more details?

Comment: On your fiddle, the tooltip always says "Custom tooltip".

Comment: Hi @Vladimir Despotovic, I have used the `refresh` method to show a tooltip and the `move` method to position it near to a label. The inner string is defined in `tooltip.formatter` - it is only an example, you can format it as you want.

Comment: The format is perfect. However, I can't get the correct data in it. It seems to be isolated that way you implemented it, so I can't input any of my data in it.

Comment: The usual method by accessing the "this.pos" and "this" doesn't work for some reason. These variables don't give me the values of index of the point.

Comment: You can add the required values in the `getLabelConfig` function, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/897fwohy/

Comment: Ok, that brings some more on x axis (not exactly what I wanted, but getting close). But now the tooltip for the point  itself is messed up (always appearing "Point").

Comment: You need to edit the first part of the `formatter` function, for example here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5foLd170/ I have used the default formatter.

Comment: Hi @Potaczek . I added the fiddle of what problems I am having now. I also havae the label represented by a small red square. The tooltip is always displayed under. I need it to be displayed over the label, anc cannot seem to make it. Could you take a look? Thanks very much, seems like you are an expert in highcharts.

Comment: I will accept your answer and I opened new question for the newly arisen problem that I have:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65321590/how-to-set-z-index-level-on-label-tooltip-in-highcharts-js